# MySQL Query: Is There any Query such "BUT NOT IN <blank>"?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any query that says

> "in .... but not in ....." ?

Let's say I have a table about "double agent".

This table has Name, Nationality, and Age.

```
+-------------------------+
| Name    Nationality Age |
+-------------------------+
| Jony    US          20  |
| Jony    China       20  |
| Adam    Argentina   25  |
| Lukas   China       39  |
| Lukas   US          39  |
+-------------------------+
```

Then I'm planning to  output a list for all agent that has China as nationality but not US.

What I wrote

> Select name from agent where nationality = 'China' and nationality != 'US'

As predicted, it didn't print anything because it is wrong.

I know maybe it is a stupid answer, but can anyone correct me? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe make two separate databases?

Comment: What values are you expecting to be returned? What values would you expect to be returned with a sixth row `Name=Amy, Nationality=China, Age=30` without a matching `Name=Amy, Nationality=US, Age=30` row?

Comment: There is no agent that fits the criteria :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using aggregation and `having`.  I think the clearest approach is:

```
select name
from agent
group by name
having sum(nationality = 'China') > 0 and
       sum(nationality = 'US') = 0;
```

There are definitely other methods.  Here is one that doesn't require `select distinct` or `group by`:

```
select a.name
from agent a
where a.nationality = 'China' and
      not exists (select 1 from agent a2 where a2.name = a.name and a2.nationality = 'US');
```

With indexes on `agent(nationality, name)` and `agent(name, nationality)`, this probably has the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
from agent 
where  nationality = 'China' 
and nationality <> 'US';
```

Comment: Isnt this will print Adam from Argentina?

Comment: Okay. So you want only those agents who has nationality = china ? @MasAdam

Comment: Yes. Is it possible?

Comment: @MasAdam Yes it is. Try my updated answer. It works as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two tools to make this work:

1. `distinct`:  This will let you get rid of your duplicates
2. A sub-query to filter out those with US.

   select
       distinct name
   from
       agent
   where
       nationality = 'China'
       and not exists (
           select
               *
           from
               agent
           where
               nationality = 'US'
       )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all agents that are in China but not the US, you can apply the filter in `having`

```
select name from mytable
where nationality in ('US', 'China')
group by name
having sum(nationality = 'US') = 0
```

Note that in your sample data all agents that are in China are also in the US, so this query wouldn't return any rows in that case.

Comment: `HAVING SUM(Nationality = 'US') = 0`